# Spring tool suite plugin conflict not allowing to import maven projects

Tags: maven-plugin, spring-tool-suite, spring-io

I have been using my installation of Spring Tool Suite (Version: 3.5.0.RELEASE Build Id: 201404011851) for quite a while now and have many different work spaces in it. I do not when or which update or something caused the problem, but i discovered it when i tried to import a new maven project into a new work space i created recently. I was trying to import another copy of the same project which is working fine in my previous work spaces. All the previous work spaces works just fine with this STS installations, only that i am unable to create any new work space. Here are the errors that occur when i try to import.

```
An internal error occurred during:"Importing maven project"

    An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject"
```

This obviously cause any attempt to update or build the project to fail.

The version for Maven compiler plugin is 2.3.2. When i try to update all the plugins, it shows a conflict between plugins with the following details.

```
    Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7)
  Software being installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1.201408250826-RELEASE-e38 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.1.201408250826-RELEASE-e38)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Views 3.6.100.v20120521-2329 (org.eclipse.ui.views 3.6.100.v20120521-2329)
    Views 3.6.100.v20120705-114010 (org.eclipse.ui.views 3.6.100.v20120705-114010)
    Views 3.6.100.v20120521-2332 (org.eclipse.ui.views 3.6.100.v20120521-2332)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.8.0.v20120607-071945-9gF7jI7nG5qByXMVdkhRMWBQlF4PnDCLybDCPQ (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.0.v20120607-071945-9gF7jI7nG5qByXMVdkhRMWBQlF4PnDCLybDCPQ)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.views [3.6.100.v20120521-2332]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.8.1.v20120815-074604-9gF7jI7wG5qDyZMWGg8NPvDbfWFWlIJU-kYaOQ (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.1.v20120815-074604-9gF7jI7wG5qDyZMWGg8NPvDbfWFWlIJU-kYaOQ)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.views [3.6.100.v20120521-2332]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.8.1.v20130118-180812-9jF7oIBFG8eU2pim-VbIlTuQjY0RWWK3x-bv4I (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.1.v20130118-180812-9jF7oIBFG8eU2pim-VbIlTuQjY0RWWK3x-bv4I)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.views [3.6.100.v20120521-2332]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.views [3.6.100.v20120705-114010]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1.201408250826-RELEASE-e38 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.1.201408250826-RELEASE-e38)
    To: org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group [3.6.1.201408250826-RELEASE-e38]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite Package 3.6.1.201408250826-RELEASE-e38 (org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group 3.6.1.201408250826-RELEASE-e38)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.8.0,4.0.0)
```

I am totally stuck because of these conflicts. Since there are a lot of configurations i have done in this installation, i would like to resolve the conflicts in this one itself rather than switching to a fresh installation.

Comment: THe conflicts in the second 'block' (cannot satisfy dependencies) seem to be because you are trying to install Eclipse 4.2 components into Eclipse 3.8 based version of STS. In particular: "Software being installed: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1..." <-> Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1.201408250826-RELEASE-e38 (the e38 means this is a version of STS based on Eclipse 3.8). If you want to upgrade to something more recent I suggest you start with STS 3.6.1 based on Eclipse 4.4 and install current versions of everything based on Eclipse 4.4.

Comment: I too figured that out. But now how do i get out of this problem ??

Comment: I suggest a 'fresh' start. I.e download STS 3.6.1 based on Eclipse 4.4 and install what you need into that. You can not really upgrade an existing installation from one version of Eclipse to the next.

Comment: Any way to export configurations and plugins ??

Comment: Preferences, yes: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftimpandexp.htm

Comment: Plugins, I don't think so but I could be wrong. Even if it were possible I wouldn't recommend it because you want to install more recent versions of plugins anyway.